# Given $F$ a field, $F \times F$ need not be a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I'm trying to prove that the Cartesian product of a field $F$ is not necessarily a field. It's clear that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a field, but in order to even talk about $\mathbb{R}^2$ lacking multiplicative inverses for nonzero elements, I need to actually define a multiplication. But that doesn't prove, in general, that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a field, but only, in the case where multiplication is defined component-wise, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a field.

Is there a way to prove this without having to define an (incorrect) form of multiplication? This is the most natural multiplication, but there isn't a guarantee that there are no other forms.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Note $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, and so there _is_ a different choice of multiplication which makes $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ a field.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor And there is still another choice of multiplication (without touching the definition of addition) which makes $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ a field isomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I thought multiplying two algebraic structures **means** (by default) that the operations are defined componentwise. That's called the "direct product" If you can define the operations of addition and multiplication any way you want, then $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ can be any field or ring etc. having the cardinality of the continuum. Apparently you are thinking (rather arbitrarily it seems to me) that addition has to be defined componentwise but you can fiddle with multiplication — is that it?

Comment: A cartesian product of rings with componentwise operations *always* has zero divisors: $(1,0)(0,1) = (0,0)$. The underlying set of a field may be a cartesian product, but the operation will have to be something else.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be some confusion regarding the multiplication operation for your product. Given *rings* $A$ and $B$, we have the direct product $A \times B$ which is a ring under *coordinate-wise operations*. That is to say, $$(a, b) + (a', b') := (a + a', b + b')$$
and similarly for multiplication.

Now, given a field $F$, it is automatically a ring. So when you're asked to prove that $F \times F$ is not a field, you are meant to show that the *ring* $F \times F$ is not a field. And as already mentioned, the ring structure is already forced to be the coordinate wise one.

In fact, there is something stronger which is true: It's not just that "$F \times F$ need not be a field", we actually have that $F \times F$ is *never* a field. (I assume that $1 \neq 0$ for fields.)
Indeed, note that $(1, 0) \cdot (0, 1) = (0, 0)$. (Both the elements on the left are nonzero but their product is the zero element of the ring.)
The above actually shows that the product of any two fields is never a field. (Even more generally, the product of integral domains is never an integral domain.)

---

To emphasise a bit more: To ask about $F \times F$ being a field or not, we should be given some operations to check with. The first paragraph shows how the operations make it a ring and then it makes sense to ask whether a given ring is a field.
If we are not given any operations, then the question would become something like: "Can we define *some* operations on $F \times F$ which makes it a field?"
This becomes a bit less interesting because then we are just treating $F$ as a set and forgetting any structure that it had to begin with.